# 3D Data Interpolation in C#

Tags: c#, interpolation

I'm looking for a simple function in C# to interpolate my 3D data.
Given is already a list with around 100-150 data sets and 3 double values.

```
-25.000000  -0.770568   2.444945
-20.000000  -0.726583   2.467809
-15.000000  -0.723274   2.484167
-10.000000  -0.723114   2.506445
and so on...
```

The chart created by these values looks usually like this, I'm not sure if this counts as scattered or rather still gridded data ...

[image: Chart]

In the end **I want to hand over two double values and get the third then from the interpolation function.** It shouldn't flatten the surface, it should still go through all the given data points.

Since I'm not given the time to look into all possible algorithms and lack the mathematical background I'm a bit overwhelmed by all the possibilities that I get thrown at: Kriging, Delauney triangulation, NURBs and many more ...

In addition to that most solutions I found in the net were either for a different language, outdated or are charged by the time (e.g ilnumerics, still not sure if they have the solution)

In matlab there exists a griddata function that does exactly this (and is based on a kriging algorithm as far as I know) but in this case C# is mandatory for me.

Thank you for your help and criticism and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You might be able to steal the logic from Unity3d

Comment: phew, that looks like digging even deeper in unknown territory for me ...

Comment: Well, after a lot of research it seems that I should go with Kriging (e.g. Ilnumerics' already tested implementation) or Delauney triangulation. Now and then people recommend NURBs, still no idea yet how to implement such a solution for my task.

Comment: How did you solve this? I have the same problem. Thanks